# Как запустить asyncio код отдельно от общего event loop'a?

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, asyncio, multiprocessing, асинхронность

Есть бот в телеграмме, который парсит сайт, на каждого пользователя создается по 40-60 тасков (для каждого элемента который надо обработать),с большим количеством пользователей бот начинает тормозить, т.е время выполнения функций возрастает, хотя все, что у меня делается в этой функции это: делается запрос через Aiohttp, обрабатывается json, и добавляется в базу данных через asyncpgти есть такое предположение, что это из-за частых переключений контекста, это и приводит к тормозам основной программы. Мне сказали чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно вынести часть работы в отдельные воркеры, но как это сделать? Мне предлагают что-то связанное с rabbitmq, но мне кажется это сложным, можно ли как то asyncio код запускать через multiprocessing? или threads?

Например у меня есть функция

```
parser_result = await asyncio.gather(*(
        get_item_by_id(place=place, item_id=item_id, tg_user_id=chat_id,
                           configuration_settings=configuration_settings, user_data=user_data,
                           custom_text=custom_text, bot=bot, parser_key=parser_key,
                           tokens=tokens, user_token=user_token, access_token=access_token,
                           sem=asyncio.Semaphore(semaphore_amount))
        for item_id in items
    ))
```

Можно ли как-то эту функцию запустить отдельно от общего event loop'a? Или в подпроцесс отдельно как-то ее? В поток? Или через ProcessPoolExecutor? Чтобы основой бот не тормозил, желательно с примером кода

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут немного перемешано.

На самом деле: asyncio - асинхронность, а multiprocessing или threads - два других варианта.

Общее правило:

a) много операций ввода-вывода, но они неблокирующие - используйте асинхронность.

б) много операций ввода-вывода, но они блокирующие - используйте многопоточность.

в) много вычислений - используйте многопроцессность.

Начните с того, что выберите свой вариант (можете отредактировать вопрос с указанием варианта).

Comment: Все что у меня делается в этой функции это: делается запрос через Aiohttp, обрабатывается json, и добавляется в базу данных через asyncpg и все

Comment: А в остальном-то что делается? Вы же не можете выбрать вариант, при котором одна функция - в потоке, а все остальное - само по себе. Какой из трех вариантов лучше описывает совокупность всех функций бота? (исправил опечатку в варианте б)

Comment: Все функции делают одно и тоже, Aiohttp запрос, обработка json, добавление в базу, может в некоторых функциях выполняется обработка xml через beatifoul soup4, все остальное это просто чтение/запись с базы, запросы, работа aiogram

Comment: Странный ответ на вопрос: "Какой из трех вариантов лучше описывает?" Я ожидал одну букву увидеть - А,Б или В. Не знаю, деталей Aiohttp или блокирующие ли у вас чтение/запись. В общем, если это всё же А, то multiprocessing или threads не нужны. В асинхронном режиме попробуйте использовать Tasks для параллельного выполнения задач, но я с асинхронностью мало возился.

Comment: у меня ничего не блокирует, скорей всего а, вы про asyncio.create_task() ? если да то я пробовал их, когда пользователей много все равно начинает лагать

Comment: Тогда другого не подскажу. Если не уверены (ваше "скорее всего"), и вариантов нет, то можете многопоточность попробовать.